# Percentage of gain/loss on the sum of two commodities

Tags: algebra-precalculus

When each of the two commodities is sold at the same price and profit of $P$ %  is made on the first and a loss of $L$ % is made on the second, then the percentage gain or loss is:

$a$. $\dfrac {100(P+L)-2PL}{(100+P)+(100-L)}$.

$b$. $\dfrac {100(P-L) - 2PL}{(100+P)+(100-L)}$.

$c$. $\dfrac {100(P-L)+2PL}{(100+P)+(100-L)}$

$d$. $\dfrac {100(P-L)-2PL}{(100-P)+(100-L)}$.

My Attempt:

$$C.P_{1}=\dfrac {100\times SP}{100+ P}$$
$$C.P_{2}=\dfrac {100\times SP}{100-L}$$

How do I continue further?

Comment: I have modified your title... in order that it looks as a title, summarizing the issue. Do you agree ?

Comment: @JeanMarie, Yes.. I agree...

Comment: Hint: $P_1+P_2$ - initial value, $2SP$ - final value...